# Have batch edit a .txt file contents

Tags: batch-file

I have a large grouping of text files that have the basic pattern of

```
Files 1 Header
1. Data
2. Data
3. Data
```

My hope is to run a batch that will read it in and remove the 1st line and the three characters of the remaining lines and output like below.

```
Data
Data
Data
```

Tried building a loop to grab each line and then put it through `%line:~3%`but its not working as excepted and I'm not sure how to remove the first line of the text file to begin with.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do for /f "skip=1usebackq tokens=1*" %%t in ("%%a") do >>%%~na.new echo %%u
```

Put each filename matching `*.txt` into `%%a` then read each line of the file, skipping the first, and tokenise on the first space (default delimiter), outputting the second (`*` token = rest-of-line) token by appending to filename *samenameastextfile*.new (`%%~na.new`)

This should create a new set of files with the processed results.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to process CSV files with removing header line and first data column containing just the row number.

This batch code might be the right one for your file reformatting task:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir * /A-D /B 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1*" %%A in ("%%~I") do echo %%B>>"%%~nI.tmp"
    move /Y "%%~nI.tmp" "%%~I"
)
```

The outer loop runs command **DIR** to get a list of file names in current directory and processes each file name from this list independent on what happens with the files in current directory while running the loop.

The inner loop processes each line from current file with the exception of first line because of `skip=1`. The lines are split up because of `tokens=1*` into two strings:

- the number with the point being assigned to loop variable `A`, and
- everything else from line after the spaces/tabs after number and point being assigned to next loop variable `B`.

The string assigned to loop variable `B` is output with command **ECHO** and redirected into a temporary file with same name as current file, but file extension `tmp`.

After processing all lines of current file, the temporary file is moved over the current file to replace it, i.e. delete current file and rename temporary file to name of current file.

**Note 1:** The files in current directory should not have the file extension `tmp` as in this case the batch code would not work.

**Note 2:** The batch file should not be in current directory with the files to modify or something other than `*` is used on **DIR** command line which excludes the batch file for being also processed.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `move /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).